# Framework to help implement high resolution images, vector graphics for web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We're at the point in technology where we have clients who support various features (like svg) while others don't. We're also at the point where various clients not only support, but basically require high resolution graphics (iPhone 4+, iPad 3rd gen.).

*Is there a framework that exists that helps us present an svg when possible and/or supported as well as deliver a high resolution version if images for viewing on high resolution devices?*

I've dealt with this many times using basic CSS and some user-agent detection, but I'm looking for something that will make this process faster and more fluent. Also, now dealing with delivering different versions of actual images (multiple photos across websites, not just logos) is becoming cumbersome with the old manual way.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)?  I have never used it but I have read that it uses Javascript to detect Html5 and CSS3 features available in the browser, and allows you to use polyfills for older browsers, so that you get graceful degradation.  I know that there is an SVG portion to it as well.  There may be some ability to switch high res images for iPhone and such(I haven't looked into it....surely someone here on SO is familiar with it).  It's actually VERY robust from what I understand.  It's worth looking into, I think, tho it may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: If this answer was at all helpful to you would you please consider marking it as the accepted answer?